# Python - Saving Model

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to save my trained model and also the weights. The model is saved as a folder of a few files. How do I open the model in another project? There is no model.keras.h5 file, just a folder of a few other types of file:

```
model.save_weights('model_weights.h5')
model.save('model_keras.h5')
```

Thanks.

Comment: as I remember there should be `model.load()` which loads data from folder.

Comment: did you check documetation: [Whole model saving & loading](https://keras.io/api/saving/model_saving_and_loading/)> `save()` has special option `save_format="h5"` to write as `h5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation: [Whole model saving & loading](https://keras.io/api/saving/model_saving_and_loading/)

```
Model.save(filepath, overwrite=True, save_format=None, **kwargs)
```

`save()` has special option `save_format="h5"` to write as `h5`

Without this parameter it writes in the native `Keras` format.
And it doesn't matter if you use filename with extension `.h5`